# UIWebView delegate method not called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

The `BOOL` function isn't working on these web views. I am wondering how do I fix it so that is. I am probably missing some small detail.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{    
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] 
                           initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 119, 
                              self.view.bounds.size.width, 
                              self.view.bounds.size.height - 165)];
    webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    webView.opaque = NO;
    [webView loadHTMLString:self.item.description 
             baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.item.link]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

}

-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)inWeb 
        shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)inRequest 
        navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType{
    if (inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I think it is because you disabled user interaction you `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Whether the web view had interaction enabled would not stop the loading delegate method from being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the delegate on the webView.